# In step 3 of 4 in creating virtual network for QEMU/KVM, network IPv6 address space definition is red

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, ipv6, linux-kvm, qemu

When I search "choose ipv6 address space for virtual network," Google showed no results, but shouldn't that be in archives somewhere on the Internet?
When I type in the IPv6 network in the "Network" box, it is always red. I have tried fe80::/64, fd00::/64, and fc00::/64, but all make the box red.
I am using OpenSUSE Leap 42.2 on a Dell Inspiron 1545.
[image]

Virtual network setup IPv6 screenshot

Comment: What happens when you try a larger range?

Comment: You should be aware that you are allowed to use the `fd00/8` range, but the next 40 bits are required by the standard to be randomly chosen.

Comment: The prefix must be 64.